# Separation of interface from implementation in an inheritance hierarchy (C++ newbie)

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to figure out how to arrange some classes. This is what I've got so far ...

The top of the inheritance hierarchy is (naturally) T:

```
(T.h)
namespace foo
{
    class T
    {
    public:
        virtual void method1(std::string a_parameter) = 0;
        virtual void method2() = 0;
    };
}
```

I have two sub-classes of T with some additional methods - here are
the header files:

```
(A.h)
namespace foo
{
    class A : public T
    {
    public:
        virtual ~A() {};
        virtual void method3() = 0;
        //and a factory function
        static A* gimmeAnAyy();
    };
}

(B.h)
namespace foo
{
    class B : public T
    {
    public:
        virtual ~B() {};
        virtual void method4() = 0;
        //and a factory function
        static B* gimmeABee();
    };
}
```

The implementation classes are in the respective .cpp files:

```
(A.cpp)
namespace foo
{
    class AImpl : public A
    {
    public:
        A(std::string member_data) : m_member_data(member_data) {};
        ~A() {};
        void method3()
        {
            //something really important, can't think of it right now ;-)
        };
    private:
        std::string m_member_data;
    };
    A* A::gimmeAnAyy()
    {
        return new AImpl("this is an impl of A");
    }; 
}

(B.cpp)
namespace foo
{
    class BImpl : public B
    {
    public:
        B(std::string other_data) : m_other_data(other_data) {};
        ~B() {};
        void method4()
        {
            //something really important, can't think of it right now ;-)
        };
    private:
        std::string m_other_data;
    };
    B* B::gimmeABee()
    {
        return new BImpl("this is an imll of B");
    }; 
}
```

Now the compiler complains - rightly so - about the virtual functions 
method1() and method2() that I haven't implemented in AImpl and BImpl.

What I want is a TImpl class that both AImpl and BImpl can inherit from
so that I don't have to implement method1() and method2() in two different .cpp files.

Is it possible? Am I out to lunch? Am I asking too many rhetorical questions for a StackExchange post?

### Thanks in advance,

Mike

Comment: Make sure your base class `T` has a `virtual` destructor! As a rule of thumb: if there is any `virtual` function in a class, the destructor shall be `virtual`, too! The class is clearly intended to be inherited from and there is no cost in making the destructor `virtual`, too, but peril if it isn't `virtual`.

Comment: Sounds like a design problem.. if you can write `TImpl`, just .. impl it in T

Comment: Unless A may be derived from more than once, why bother with Impls anyway? Why not just made A the full class?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it is possible. Common practice is to use the following snippet:

```
template<typename Interface>
class TImpl : public Interface
{
public:
    virtual void method1(std::string a_parameter) { /* implementation */ }
    virtual void method2() { /* implementation */ }
};
```

And then inherit from it as follows:

```
class Aimpl : public TImpl<A>
{
public:
    virtual void method3() { /* implementation */ }
};

class Bimpl : public Timpl<B>
{
public:
    virtual void method4() { /* implementation */ }
};
```

You can put implementation of Timpl in cpp file, but then you have to explicitly instantiate it for every possible interface. This is done as follows in the cpp:

```
template<typename Interface>
void Timpl<Interface>::method1(std::string a_parameter)
{
    /* implementation */
}

template<typename Interface>
void Timpl<Interface>::method2()
{
    /* implementation */
}

template class Timpl<A>;
template class Timpl<B>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not make method1 and method2 pure virtual functions. Give them an implementation!

i.e.

declare

```
class T
    {
    public:
        virtual void method1(std::string a_parameter);
        virtual void method2();
    };
```

Define:

```
void T::method1(std::string a_parameter) { // Could use const/reference here perhaps

....

}
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is the wrong believe that it is better to have only pure `virtual` functions in your base class! Just get over it and provide a default implementation in `T`. Although there are religious believes that is bad, there isn't any technical reason not to have it. Insisting in having only pure `virtual` functions in base classes is like insisting in all music having to be [12-tone music](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve-tone_technique)!

Answer (score 0):

since both of the son classes (A & B) don't have (method1, method2) then you don't have to use the virtual. you can easily provide a default implementation in the base class and  then invoke and use these methods through the inheritance chain since the inheritance type here is public.

Answer (score 0):

In the A and B classes declaration, the methods 3 and 4 are pure virtual, so in the definition file you shouldn't gives an implementation of them. In my understand A and B are leading the implementation of the T methods and their own virtual methods to other concrete classes who inherit from them. If you thing that A and B are concrete classes, put away the "= 0" from the following lines:

```
class A : public T
{
public:
    virtual ~A() {};
    virtual void method3() = 0; // <-- Here
    //and a factory function
    static A* gimmeAnAyy();
};

class B : public T
{
public:
    virtual ~B() {};
    virtual void method4() = 0; // <-- and Here
    //and a factory function
    static B* gimmeABee();
};
```

If doesn't want to implement the methods 1 and 2 of the T class, give an empty or  a default implementation to them, in the T class or in the A and B classes.

But consider this, if you inherits from an interface, is expected that you **IMPLEMENT** that interface. :)