# Diamond Inheritance without RTTI

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, inheritance, diamond-problem

I am designing an object system where all my objects derive from a common base class. Besides objects, I have certain interfaces that I want the objects to implement. Some objects derive from multiple classes.

I am stuck with a diamond inheritance problem, in that if I make the objects inherit interfaces using `virtual public` I have to use `dynamic_cast` to cast from base to derived. Hhowever, the compiler I am using (embedded compiler for arm) does not have RTTI.

Basically, I am looking for workarounds. While searching I have come across the [visitor pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347879/c-downcasting-a-diamond-shape-inherited-object-without-rtti-dynamic-cast), but that seems a bit hacky and I end up with a lot of virtual functions that the base class has to know about. I've also come across type erasure, something like `boost::any`.

My other question is: does type erasure work in my case? Currently all of my objects are passed around as base pointers in custom shared pointers (again, `shared_ptr` is not available). Then, say, if the object implements the `callable` interface I `static_cast` the base pointer to a `callable` pointer, and call its `run` method. But certain objects needs to implement both `callable` and `iterable`, that's when the problems arise.

My main targets are GCC and Clang in C++11 mode.

```
class A 
{
public:
 virtual char* func() { return "A"; };
};
class B : public virtual A
{
public:
 //virtual char* func() { return "B"; };
};
class C : public virtual A 
{
public:
 //virtual char* func() { return "C"; };
};
```

class D : public B, public C 
{
public:
 //virtual char* func() { return "D"; };
};

D d;
A* pa = static_cast(&d);
D* pd = static_cast(pa); // can't do that! dynamic_cast does work though...

Comment: This is incredibly long. Might want to shorten it to a minimum or add a code sample to showcase the problem - it would help more people see/read your question.

Comment: My brain melted after reading the first sentence :( "besides objects I have certain interfaces that I want the objects to implement some objects " - OMG

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You say that your compiler doesn't have RTTI but in next line you say that you ended up with a lot of virtual functions. What exactly is your compiler missing?

Comment: @freakish `-fno-rtti` on GCC and Clang will disable `typeid` and `dynamic_cast`, but virtual functions still work. I guess this is similar.

Comment: @freakish exactly virtual functions work but `dynamic_cast` `typeid` is not availible.

Comment: @Mikhail check the question I linked my problem is exactly the same. I am looking for work arounds

Comment: _@Hanza_ You might use the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) aka _Static Polymorphism_ to achieve such without RTTI and virtual inheritance. Designs relying on `dynamic_cast` are bad anyways.

Comment: Right, so one way would be to implement this feature by yourself. Add an additional field to the base class, say `type`, make sure that each subclass has a different `type` and then you can easily write your own `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  CRTP won't work for my case I do not know the type ob object to cast to the correct type during compile time hence the virtual functions.

Comment: @freakish Objects already have type id unique ints that I can query, so your suggestion is a big case statement  such as if id is 1 cast to class x so on?

Comment: @HamzaYerlikaya I said that you need to know that is a major design flaw.

Comment: @HamzaYerlikaya Yes, the old school. Advantage: you don't need virtual functions at all, increased performance. Disadvantage: horrible to maintain, error prone.

Comment: I would go with visitor from what you show.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what is a major design flow?

Comment: @Hamza You misread. I meant _flaw_ actually.